# String Parsing for nested parenthesis in perl

Tags: perl, parsing

The issue is when I try to compare the input to the output file, i am unable to handle the nesting of the parenthesis, and the complexity needs to be very low. is there a parsing module for this? compatible to 5.8.4. I found modules but they needed at least 5.10.:(

Input

```
(K1=V1,K2=V2,K3=V3(K2=V2.K5=V5)K6=V6(K7=V7,K8=V8(K9=V9,K10=V10)K11=V11)K12=V12,K13=V13)
```

OUTPUT FILE

```
(K0=V0,K1=V1,K2=V2,K3=V3(K1=V1,K2=V2,K4=V4,K5=V5,K14=V14),K15=V15,K6=V6(K18=V18,K7=V7,K19=V19,K8=V8(K20=V20,K9=V9,K16=V16,K10=V10,K21=V21)K11=V11)K12=V12,K13=V13,K22=V22)
```

I need to pick up each key value pair from input and one by one verify from the output file that the value is the same. if not

I need to store the key with the existing value.( The issue is with the nesting )

INPUT

```
K3=V3(K2=V2,K5=V5)
```

OUTPUT

```
K3=V3(K1=V1,K2=V2,K4=V4,K5=V5,K14=V14)
```

The issue is that "K2=V2" inside the V3 value is to be checked inside the V3 value in the output file. So I cannot just use a regular expression to do that as K2=V2 may appear outside the V3 parenthesis too.

I was trying to create a hash of a hash of a hash but failed. could someone suggest a way I could achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide perl data structure you want to get for `K3=V3(K1=V1,K2=V2,K4=V4,K5=V5,K14=V14)` input string?

Answer (score 0):

The following code builds the hash of hashes. Note that values (V3) are lost if they contain an inner hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub to_hash {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\( | \)$//gx; # Remove the outer parentheses.

    my @stack = {};
    my @keys;

    while (length $string) {
        $string =~ s/^([^,=()]+) = ([^(),]*)//x or die $string;
        my ($key, $value) = ($1, $2);
        $stack[-1]{$key} = $value;
        next if $string =~ s/^,//;

        if ($string =~ s/^\(//) {
            push @stack, {};
            push @keys, $key;

        } elsif ($string =~ s/^\),?//) {
            my $last = pop @stack;
            $stack[-1]{ pop @keys } = $last;
        }
    }

    return $stack[0]
}

my $input = '(K1=V1,K2=V2,K3=V3(K2=V2,K5=V5)K6=V6(K7=V7,K8=V8(K9=V9,K10=V10)K11=V11)K12=V12,K13=V13)';

print Dumper to_hash($input);
```

### Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'K2' => 'V2',
          'K13' => 'V13',
          'K6' => {
                    'K7' => 'V7',
                    'K8' => {
                              'K9' => 'V9',
                              'K10' => 'V10'
                            },
                    'K11' => 'V11'
                  },
          'K3' => {
                    'K2' => 'V2',
                    'K5' => 'V5'
                  },
          'K12' => 'V12',
          'K1' => 'V1'
        };
```

Comment: OP came back which data where the value is blank. Adjusted your code.

Comment: @ikegami: It also seems there are commas after `)`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Nested parens either suggests an application of `Text::Balanced` and its `extract_bracketed` function, or building yourself a little parser subclass on `Parser::MGC`. Using the latter to build a little "convert string into data structure" parser is usually pretty straightforward for simple examples like this.